# <ul> <li> centered, not moving down.. unsure why / how to fix

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin, padding

The `<nav>` should be aligned to the left, below the logo and slogan. However, despite attempting to do so with both `margin` and `padding` it remains above the logo and centered on the page. Any help with how to rectify this is greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<header>
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="GEC logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="slogan">
        <h1>Revolutionizing Potential</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Coaching Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
/* Header */

header {
    margin-top: 95px;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
}

#slogan {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 90px;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with the images included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your CSS add:

```
nav {
    clear:both;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uGX2Z/)**

Comment: In my opinion thats not a great solution to the problem. I think you should always try not to use the clear, and if you code right you dont even need id.

Answer (score 0):

First off what I always do is to give all elements default widths and hights.

The nav is an inline element and not a block.
to refrain from using clear fixes you should put a div element around the logo and the slogan.
like this:
HTML

```
<header>

  <div id="header_top">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="GEC logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="slogan">
        <h1>Revolutionizing Potential</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Coaching Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Now you can just give the header_top div a display block and a overlfow:hidden.
That will give make the header_top div grow with its content.

Now giv you nav a display:block style and it is done

I tested it local on my notebook and it worked like a charm :)

add:
CSS

```
#header_top{
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
}
nav{
display: block;    
}
```